# How can I wrap every v-if in my Vue code in a transition?

Tags: vue.js

The task of having to write

```
  
<transition name="fade">
    <div v-if="condition">

    </div>
</transition>
```

Is manual labour. Is there any shortcut way of wrapping every v-if with a transition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom Vue component:

```
// AppTransition.vue
<template>
<transition name='fade'>
  <div v-if='show'>
    <slot />
  </div>
</transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    show: Boolean
  }
}
</script>
```

and then use it as follows:

```
<template>
  <AppTransition :show='condition'>
    <div>Hello, world</div>
  </AppTransition>
</template>

<script>
// You can avoid importing it everywhere by making it a global component, see https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html
import AppTransition from './AppTransition'

export default {
  components: { AppTransition }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This could be further improved by adding to main.js: 
```import AppTransition from './AppTransition.vue'``` ```Vue.component('AppTransition ', AppTransition);``` to make it a global component. However there is the inconvenience of not being able to set classes directly to the parent div as any classes to the component would go onto the transition tag

Comment: You could use `inheritAttrs: false` and then use `<div v-if='show' v-bind="$attrs"><slot /></div>` in your inner `div`